# Add formula in if else statement

Tags: crystal-reports

I need a formula in a display string to change the text in a crosstab. I have to calculate some numeric value based database values and replace some values with "". Below is the formula for numeric values:

```
shared numberVar array sgpa;
shared stringVar array stds;
shared booleanVar array show_gpa;

numberVar i;
stringVar _sgpa:="";

for i:=1 to count(stds)
do
if stds[i] = GridRowColumnValue("TAB_COURSE_GRADE.STD_ID2") then _sgpa := 
iif(show_gpa[i], ToText(sgpa[i],"##.##"),"");

_sgpa
```

How can I effectively add this if/else statement when it otherwise gives me "A string is required here" errors:

```
shared numberVar array sgpa;

shared numberVar array sgpa;
shared stringVar array stds;
shared booleanVar array show_gpa;

numberVar i;
stringVar _sgpa:="";


If CurrentFieldValue = "UF"
Then ""
Else 
for i:=1 to count(stds)
do
if stds[i] = GridRowColumnValue("TAB_COURSE_GRADE.STD_ID2") then _sgpa := iif(show_gpa[i], ToText(sgpa[i],"##.##"),"");

_sgpa
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not separate it into multiple formulas?

Make an individual formula `Calculations` which will perform *all* the math necessary to get the display value, but doesn't do the `CurrentFieldValue` check. Then make a second formula called `IfElse` which will look something like:

```
IF CurrentFieldValue = "UF" THEN "" ELSE CSTR({@Calculations})
```